# Why the q th power of a root is again a root？

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots, finite-fields

If $f(x)$ is a q-polynomial over $F_q$, q is prime, the roots of $f(x)$ form a vector space over $F_q$. Why the qth power of a root is again a root?

Comment: Hint: What happens when you raise the original polynomial to the power $q$?

Comment: I got it. Let $f(x)=a_0x^{q^m}+a_1x^{q^(m-1)}+...+a_{m-1}x^{q}+a_mx$, $\alpha$ is root of $f(x)$, then $$f(\alpha)=a_0\alpha^{q^m}+a_1\alpha^{q^(m-1)}+...+a_{m-1}\alpha^{q}+a_m\alpha=0$$, $$f(\alpha^q)=a_0(\alpha^{q^m})^q+a_1(\alpha^{q^{m-1}})^q+...+a_{m-1}(\alpha^{q})^q+a_m(\alpha^{q})=f(\alpha)^q$$ So,$$f(\alpha^q)=f(\alpha)^q=0$$

Comment: @Laura, you can move your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $0=f(\alpha)^q=f(\alpha^q)$ because the map $x \mapsto x^q$ is an endomorphism of $\mathbb F_q$.

This map is called the [Frobenius endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism).